# Out of memory when using readStream on big files

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcloud-node

I tried to download 50GB File from Google Cloud Platform to my local machine.
I used GCP's getReadStream function, and I saw that the memory usage was increasing dramatically until the process crashed.

What is the best practice for using your readStream? Or is there any workaround for that problem?

Thanks!

Github issue for @google-cloud/storage NPM package: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/492